# How can I change a specific value in a nested dictionary inside of JSON array?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I can't figure out how to change a specific value of a dictionary inside of another dictionary.

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "characters":{
        "name" : "John",
        "inventory" : {"Apples" : 12}
    },
  }
]
```

Python:

```
with open("json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for character in data["characters"]:
    if character["name"] == "John":
    print(!)
```

I want to be able to change John's amount of Apples inside of the if statement.

I tried inputting:

```
data["characters"][character["name"]]["inventory"]["Apples"] -= 12
```

and then dumping with another open in Write.

Comment: 1. you fix the comma in the JSON 2. you parse the JSON 3. you change the data 4. you serialize to JSON again. You seem to have done 2. so far and for 3. you have to keep in mind that there is an outer list (array in JSON terms).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to iterate a dict is:

```
for keys,values in data.items():    
    if values['name'] == "John":
          values['inventory']['Apples']-=12
```